# Python itertools.combinations early cutoff

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, for-in-loop

In the following code,the only item that is printed from object 'c' in the looped product is the first one, although both 'c' and 'd' contain 3 items and all 3 items of 'd' are iterated over properly.

```
from itertools import combinations

c,d = combinations(map(str, range(3)),2), combinations(map(str, range(3)),2)
for x in c:
 for y in d:
  print(x,y)
```

Typecasting generators to list solves this problem and prints 9 lines but why does this occur in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `c` and `d` are both iterators, and after the first time through the inner loop, `d` has been exhausted.  The simplest way to fix this is to do:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

c = combinations(map(str, range(3)),2)
d = combinations(map(str, range(3)),2)

for x, y in product(c, d):
    print(x,y)
```

This produces:

```
('0', '1') ('0', '1')
('0', '1') ('0', '2')
('0', '1') ('1', '2')
('0', '2') ('0', '1')
('0', '2') ('0', '2')
('0', '2') ('1', '2')
('1', '2') ('0', '1')
('1', '2') ('0', '2')
('1', '2') ('1', '2')
```

Comment: It was that simple! and I kept thinking that there was something wrong with the first generator. +1 for itertools.product based approach.